# .NET Forms Authentication - Securing legacy site with mixed content

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, cookies, forms-authentication

I've been tasked with upgrading/replacing the existing security on a legacy site of ours that uses a mix of classic asp and .net applications. The site had been using a custom ISAPI plugin to secure the pages, and needs to be updated.

I've created a simple .net shim application and placed it as a virtual application under the root directory of the site, in a path called `/security`.

At the root of the website, I created a web.config with the following settings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <location allowOverride="true">
        <system.web>
            <authentication mode="Forms">
                <forms name=".APPSAUTH"
                loginUrl="Security/Authentication/"
                path="/"
                protection="All"
                requireSSL="false"
                slidingExpiration="true"
                timeout="15"/>
            </authentication>
            <authorization>
                <deny users="?"/>
            </authorization>
            <machineKey validation="SHA1"
            decryption="AES"
            validationKey="REMOVED"
            decryptionKey="REMOVED"/>
        </system.web>
    </location>
    <location path="Security">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="*"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear/>
                <add value="Default.htm"/>
                <add value="Default.asp"/>
                <add value="default.aspx"/>
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <modules>
            <remove name="FormsAuthentication"/>
            <add name="FormsAuthentication"
            type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule"
            preCondition=""/>
            <remove name="UrlAuthorization"/>
            <add name="UrlAuthorization"
            type="System.Web.Security.UrlAuthorizationModule"/>
            <remove name="DefaultAuthentication"/>
            <add name="DefaultAuthentication"
            type="System.Web.Security.DefaultAuthenticationModule"/>
        </modules>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The security shim's web config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <!-- REMOVED -->
    </appSettings>
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms name=".APPSAUTH"
                   loginUrl="~/Security/Authentication/"
                   path="/"
                   protection="All"
                   requireSSL="false"
                   slidingExpiration="true"
                   timeout="15"/>
        </authentication>
        <compilation debug="true"
                     targetFramework="4.7.2"/>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2"/>
        <machineKey validation="SHA1"
                    decryption="AES"
                    validationKey="REMOVED"
                    decryptionKey="REMOVED"/>
    </system.web>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers"
                                  publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0"
                                 newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages"
                                  publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0"
                                 newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc"
                                  publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.7.0"
                                 newVersion="5.2.7.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
    <system.codedom>
        <compilers>
            <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp"
                      extension=".cs"
                      type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                      warningLevel="4"
                      compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
            <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript"
                      extension=".vb"
                      type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                      warningLevel="4"
                      compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
        </compilers>
    </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

The application pool is set to integrated mode.

Everything works as far as signing in goes - I try to access `default.htm` at the root of the website and I am redirected to the signin.aspx page for my security shim. Once I go through the authentication processes and the user is validated against a custom user store, I call

`FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(response.UserId, false);` to set the auth cookie, then redirect to a default.aspx page in the security application.

The default.aspx page shows some simple debug information:

```
Logged in: True
User: REMOVED
```

Using the debug window in chrome, I can see that I am passing the auth cookie:

[image: Chrome browser cookie]

However, once I try to access any page outside of the security folder, I am redirected back to the security application.

Having enabled cs(cookie) in the WC3 logs, I see that the request is being sent with the auth cookie from the browser:

```
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Cookie) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2021-02-24 18:53:15 SERVER_IP_ADDRESS GET /Security/Authentication/Default - 80 USERID SERVER_IP_ADDRESS Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/88.0.4324.182+Safari/537.36 .APPSAUTH=REMOVED http://SERVER_IP_ADDRESS/Security/Authentication/Callback 200 0 0 13
2021-02-24 18:53:17 SERVER_IP_ADDRESS GET / - 80 - 10.76.136.8 - - - 302 0 0 7
2021-02-24 18:53:17 SERVER_IP_ADDRESS GET / - 80 - 10.76.136.9 - - - 302 0 0 1
2021-02-24 18:53:17 SERVER_IP_ADDRESS GET /default.htm.htm - 80 - SERVER_IP_ADDRESS Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/88.0.4324.182+Safari/537.36 .APPSAUTH=REMOVED http://SERVER_IP_ADDRESS/Security/Authentication/Default 302 0 0 7
2021-02-24 18:53:17 SERVER_IP_ADDRESS GET /Security/Authentication/ ReturnUrl=%2fdefault.htm.htm 80 USERID SERVER_IP_ADDRESS Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/88.0.4324.182+Safari/537.36 .APPSAUTH=REMOVED http://SERVER_IP_ADDRESS/Security/Authentication/Default 302 0 0 8
2021-02-24 18:53:17 SERVER_IP_ADDRESS GET /Security/Authentication/Default - 80 USERID SERVER_IP_ADDRESS Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/88.0.4324.182+Safari/537.36 .APPSAUTH=REMOVED http://SERVER_IP_ADDRESS/Security/Authentication/Default 200 0 0 1
```

From the logs, I see that I am getting a 302 even though my browser is forwarding the auth cookie.

What am I missing?

Comment: I've created a separate .NET app, using the same authentication settings as the security shim above and can get the user's session, id, etc. I am able to hit that page and not be redirected. Only am redirected from static content and classic asp pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that the module used by IIS 10 was not the same version as the one used by my security mvc application - I was using .NET Standard 4.7.2, IIS was using an older verison.

Setting the `compatibilityMode` attribute on the machineKey tag allowed IIS to properly decrypt the auth token and validate that the user was logged in:

```
<machineKey compatibilityMode="Framework20SP2" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" validationKey="..." decryptionKey="..." />
```

Enabling failed request tracing let me see that the request was getting the cookie for non-.NET requests, but the auth token could not be decrypted/validated. That eventually led me to the problem.